# Ruby Rails %r and %w

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Two questions that I believe are connected and I think are regex related but have me stumped after some fruitless googling.

```
validates :image_url, format: { with: %r{\.(gif|jpg)\Z}i }
```

My guesses:  similar to ruby/regex i = ignore case, single pipe means 'or'.  Guessing \Z means end of string.  The brackets are just containers unlike ruby/regex where they signify something wildly different.

But what does the %r do?  I haven't run across that in ruby/regex.

```
ok_urls = %w{ fred.gif fred.jpg FRED.Jpg}
```

%r and %w seem to be doing the same thing so I'm confused why there are two separate commands to do the same thing.  Sorry if this isn't very clear.

Comment: Have you tried to enter `%w{foo bar}` and `%r{foo bar}` in IRB / rails console?

Comment: Negative.  I didn't think that irb would except those commands since they seemed like rails commands.  But lo and behold it handled it with no problemos.  And that was actually a really good way to figure it out.  After using both I ran r.class and w.class  Turns out r creates a regex in a variable (didn't know that was possible) and w parses it out into an array by spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) holds a regular expression, used to match a pattern against strings. *Regexps* are created using the `/.../` and `%r{...}` literals, and by the `Regexp::new` constructor.

> %r and %w seem to be doing the same thing so I'm confused..

```
%w{ fred.gif fred.jpg FRED.Jpg}
# => ["fred.gif", "fred.jpg", "FRED.Jpg"]
%r{ a b }
# => / a b /
```

No. They are not same, as you can see above.

[One thing I noticed](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/21370656103/creating-regular-expressions-with-r-literals) with `%r{}`, as you don't need to escape *slashes*.

```
# /../ literals:
url.match /http:\/\/example\.com\//
# => #<MatchData "http://example.com/">

# %r{} literals:
url.match %r{http://example\.com/}
# => #<MatchData "http://example.com/">
```

[Use `%r`](http://www.relishapp.com/womply/ruby-style-guide/docs/percent-literals) only for regular expressions matching more than one '/' character.

```
# bad
%r(\s+)

# still bad
%r(^/(.*)$)
# should be /^\/(.*)$/

# good
%r(^/blog/2011/(.*)$)
```

Comment: "One thing I noticed with %r{}" - that's what it's **for**! :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Humm.. :-)